# Visual studio code devcontainer error reading from server: EOF

Tags: docker, vscode-devcontainer

I'm trying to do a devcontainer setup with vscode on linux (fedora 37) but I always get the error you can see in the image link below

[failed to receive status: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = error reading from server: EOF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkhsC.jpg)

These are my configuration files:

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM php:7.4-apache
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        git \
        unzip \
        libfreetype6-dev \
        libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
        libpng-dev \
        libzip-dev \
        libicu-dev \
        libc-client-dev \
        libkrb5-dev \
        libmagickwand-dev && \
    docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg=/usr/include/ --enable-gd && \
    docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd && \
    docker-php-ext-configure intl && \
    PHP_OPENSSL=yes docker-php-ext-configure imap --with-kerberos --with-imap-ssl && \
    docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) imap && \
    docker-php-ext-install zip && \
    docker-php-ext-install mysqli && \
    docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql && \
    docker-php-ext-install intl && \
    docker-php-ext-install calendar && \
    docker-php-ext-install exif && \
    docker-php-ext-install gettext && \
    docker-php-ext-install sockets && \
    yes '' | pecl install imagick && docker-php-ext-enable imagick && \
    a2enmod rewrite && \
    a2enmod headers && \
    a2enmod cgi && \
    a2enmod proxy_fcgi && \
    apt-get remove -y libfreetype6-dev \
        libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
        libpng-dev \
        libzip-dev \
        libicu-dev \
        libc-client-dev \
        libkrb5-dev \
        libmagickwand-dev && \
    apt-get clean -y

RUN sed -i -e '/.* rights="none".*pattern="PDF"/s/ rights="none"/ rights="read|write"/g' /etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml
COPY --from=composer:2.5 /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer
```

devcontainer.json:

```json
{
    "name": "PHP",
    "build": {
        "context": ".",
        "dockerfile": "Dockerfile"
    },
    "forwardPorts": [ "8000:80" ],
    "customizations": {
        "vscode": {
            "extensions": [
                "donjayamanne.git-extension-pack",
                "waderyan.gitblame",
                "ms-azuretools.vscode-docker",
                "p1c2u.docker-compose",
                "ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh",
                "TabNine.tabnine-vscode",
                "DEVSENSE.phptools-vscode",
                "xdebug.php-pack"
            ]
        }
    },
    "workspaceMount":"source=${localWorkspaceFolder},target=/workspace,type=bind,consistency=cached",
    "workspaceFolder": "/workspace",
}
```

Thank you very much for the help

The information I found on the internet says that the problem is docker, but docker is fine.

I run my docker build and it finishes successfully, but devconteiner throws the error every time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most likely related to a bug in Docker stack, introduced in recent Docker 23 (check your version to make sure the below applies to you).

VSC issue: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/7958. There you can find a workaround and links to upstream trackers that deal with the issue directly.

I can confirm the workaround of disabling BUILDKIT_INLINE_CACHE works, that is setting the following in .devcontainer.json allows for VSC to start:

```
{
    "build": {
        "args": {
            "BUILDKIT_INLINE_CACHE": "0"
        }
    }
}
```

The issue itself is supposed to be [fixed already](https://github.com/docker/buildx/issues/1325#issuecomment-1416444770), but may not have landed in your distribution yet.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I checked the links and verified my docker version and certanly it was 23.0.0 version, I upgraded to 23.0.1 and the problem was fixed.

I was thinking the problem was related to the dev container plugin itself, never thought it was a docker bug

Comment: I have this issue with 23.0.1 as well...

Comment: That's weird - for me 23.0.1 fixed the issue as well.